# Preparing a Place

Tags: heaven, second-coming

In the famous passage of John 14:1-3, Jesus uses the phrase "prepare a place for you".  It is said as though He needed time to do it.  With the resources of omnipotence, why does Jesus mean by preparing a place?

Comment: This isn't long enough to be an answer. Jesus would be leaving (soon but not yet) to prepare a place in heaven for the disciples. With time they would eventually attain heaven.

Comment: There is no suggestion of any 'time' at all required. The statement 'prepare a place' has no time-significance attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gospel of John pointed out many parallels to the Pentateuch.  For example, his beginning to Gen 1:1.  Here are some others:

> And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth.  (John 1:14, ESV)

Dwelt translates ἐσκήνωσεν, the verb form of σκηνή (tent).  Thus, this references the tabernacle, and note how God showed his glory with the tabernacle.

> For the law was given through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.  (John 1:17, ESV)

These are a few examples.  The point is look at:

> So they set out from the mount of the LORD three days’ journey. And the ark of the covenant of the LORD went before them three days’ journey, to seek out a resting place for them.  (Num. 10:33, ESV)

Also note that Jesus used much symbolic language, especially as recorded in the Gospel of John.  In this passage is Thomas’ confusion:

> Thomas said to him, “Lord, we do not know where you are going. How can we know the way?”  Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.  (John 14:5–6, ESV)

Then, Philip’s question also:

> Philip said to him, “Lord, show us the Father, and it is enough for us.”  Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and you still do not know me, Philip? Whoever has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’?  Do you not believe that I am in the Father and the Father is in me? The words that I say to you I do not speak on my own authority, but the Father who dwells in me does his works.  Believe me that I am in the Father and the Father is in me, or else believe on account of the works themselves.  (John 14:8–11, ESV)

Roberson points out:

> … Jesus had sent Peter and John to make ready (this very verb) for the passover meal (Mark 14:12=Matt. 26:17).

Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (Jn 14:2). Nashville, TN: Broadman Press.

Your question sounds like those of Thomas and Philip.  What did Jesus actually do to prepare a place for us?  He died on the cross to make it possible for us to go to heaven (John 3:16; 1 Peter 3:18).  **The timing is the time it took for Jesus to go on trial and be crucified.**  You may also want to include the three days in the tomb before he ascended to the Father (Num. 10:3).

> We have this as a sure and steadfast anchor of the soul, a hope that enters into the inner place behind the curtain, where Jesus has gone as a forerunner on our behalf, having become a high priest forever after the order of Melchizedek.  (Heb. 6:19–20, ESV)

Appendix: Commentaries

Many commentaries don’t discuss what “preparing a place” means.  I wouldn’t call the interpretation in this answer novel.   Paterson gives the same interpretation:

> Jesus said that it was only because of his going (his death and resurrection) that he would be able to provide plenty of room for all God’s children. He was not saying he had to go to heaven to start the building or refurbishment work—it was already there—but that it would only be through the cross that men and women would ever be qualified to enter the place where God is.

Paterson, A. (2010). Opening Up John’s Gospel (p. 120). Leominster: Day One Publications.

These commentators have the interpretation presented in this answer as possible or included.

> Christ prepared a heavenly home for His disciples by His atoning death, resurrection and ascension; but considering that the heavenly mansions are merely intermistic abodes, the term may perhaps also refer to the building up of the heavenly Jerusalem, which is ultimately to descend upon the new earth.

Lange, J. P., & Schaff, P. (2008). A commentary on the Holy Scriptures: John (pp. 435–436). Bellingham, WA: Logos Bible Software.

> I go to prepare a place for you. If the separation was to be an eternal one he would have forewarned them. Rather, he goes before to prepare a home for them where they can all be together. The departure of Jesus was needful to open an entrance to them and us. From the cross he went to rend the vail of the temple “thus signifying that the way into heaven was now open.” On the cross he shed the blood that cleanses us from sin, defiled with which we could never enter. He not only prepares a place for us, but prepares the way. It is a blessed thought that in heaven his thoughts are upon us and that he is preparing a congenial home for us. Just how he makes that preparation we may not understand but the fact is sure.

Johnson, B. W. (1886). John: the New Testament commentary, vol. III (p. 217). St. Louis, MO: Christian Board of Publication.

> (2) It tells us of the function of Jesus. He said: ‘I am going to prepare a place for you.’ One of the great thoughts of the New Testament is that Jesus goes on in front for us to follow. He opens up a way so that we may follow in his steps. One of the great words which is used to describe Jesus is the word prodromos (Hebrews 6:20). The Authorized Version and the Revised Standard translate it as forerunner. There are two uses of this word which light up the picture within it. In the Roman army, the prodromoi were the reconnaissance troops. They went ahead of the main body of the army to blaze the trail and to ensure that it was safe for the rest of the troops to follow. The harbour of Alexandria was very difficult to approach. When the great corn ships came into it, a little pilot boat was sent out to guide them along the channel into safe waters. That pilot boat was called the prodromos. It went first to make it safe for others to follow. That is what Jesus did. He blazed the way to heaven and to God that we might follow in his steps.

Barclay, W. (2001). The Gospel of John (Vol. 2, p. 181). Louisville, KY: Edinburgh.

> “I go to prepare a place for you” may have two meanings. The Lord Jesus went to Calvary to prepare a place for His own. It is through His atoning death that believers are assured a place there. But also the Lord went back to heaven to prepare a place. We do not know very much about this place, but we know that provision is being made for every child of God—“a prepared place for a prepared people!”

MacDonald, W. (1995). Believer’s Bible Commentary: Old and New Testaments. (A. Farstad, Ed.) (p. 1545). Nashville: Thomas Nelson.

Matthew Henry’s commentary is probably the what you consider a more traditional interpretation:

> 2. Believe and consider that the design of Christ’s going away was to prepare a place in heaven for his disciples. “You are grieved to think of my going away, whereas I go on your errand, as the forerunner; I am to enter for you.” He went to prepare a place for us; that is, (1.) To take possession for us, as our advocate or attorney, and so to secure our title as indefeasible. Livery of seisin was given to Christ, for the use and behoof of all that should believe on him. (2.) To make provision for us as our friend and father. The happiness of heaven, though prepared before the foundation of the world, yet must be further fitted up for man in his fallen state. It consisting much in the presence of Christ there, it was therefore necessary that he should go before, to enter into that glory which his disciples were to share in. Heaven would be an unready place for a Christian if Christ were not there. He went to prepare a table for them, to prepare thrones for them, Lu. 22:30. Thus Christ declares the fitness of heaven’s happiness for the saints, for whom it is prepared.

Henry, M. (1994). Matthew Henry’s commentary on the whole Bible: complete and unabridged in one volume (p. 2012). Peabody: Hendrickson.

Comment: Many thanks, Perry Webb - a fascinating interpretation, albeit novel (at least to me).

Comment: What do you make of the previous verse (v1) where Jesus speaks of His Father's house with many rooms where He going to prepare a place - that does not sound like the cross and the grave.

Comment: The passage in Hebrews says what Jesus did when he ascended to the Father.  Jesus spoke of the Father's house as if the rooms already existed.  Do you really think someone had to physically get the rooms ready for us?

Comment: That is the point of the question in the first place.  If you mean Heb 6:19, 20, that is discussing the heavenly sanctuary - is that your reference?

Comment: @Mac yes Heb. 6:19-20.

Comment: See commentaries added as an appendix.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't Jesus that needs time, but humanity.

In John 13:36 (NLT), Jesus tells Peter "*You can’t go with me now, but you will follow me later*".

A few verses later, in John 14:2 (NLT), Jesus says "*There is more than enough room in my Father’s home. If this were not so, would I have told you that I am going to prepare a place for you?*".

His disciples are concerned because Jesus has just told them he is going to leave them.  They are feeling abandoned.  So Jesus is reassuring them by reminding them of other promises he has made concerning their future.

In many parables and other allusions, Jesus has said that he would go away to inherit a kingdom, that in his absence he would leave everything in the charge of his stewards, and that when he returns they would inherit positions with him.

This is made explicit in Revelation 20:6, "*Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection. For them the second death holds no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with him a thousand years.*".

The Disciples, and all those that are saved, both living and dead, will be born again as spirit beings at Jesus's return.  They will be the teachers and rulers during the millennial kingdom of God.

Jesus will return and his disciples and others will be assigned specific titles and duties, but not until humanity is on the brink of extinction.

His return is delayed by the progress of human history.  It's certainly not because *Jesus* needs more time.